# Can't Format my USB disk after trying to make it an install bootable key for Linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, usb, bootable-media

Few days ago, I wanted to install CentOS 7 on my computer, without passing through a VM.

I downloaded Win32diskmanager to make a bootable disk with an installer for CentOS from an ISO I downloaded on their repo. It was working fine, until a moment where the process failed, no message, nothing.

Until then, my USB hard drive is not visible in Windows. Well, not really because I can see it in the Disk Manager. I see my HD, it is "Online", but when I try to format it, a message tell me that the HD is offline and I can't to that. I tried to understand why through "diskpart" on cmd, and I was that that was the partition that was offline.

Now, I don't really know what to do. Does someone have any idea about what I should look to, what I should try ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you delete the existing "volumes" (partitions) on your flash drive?

Comment: Yeah, I can delete them, create them, but not format them.
When I try to format the volume, it tells me that it is offline, and that I should assign it a letter. 
And when I try to assign it a letter, it tells me that the volume can't be found.

Comment: Never had that behaviour before, does this happen to all flash drives (using the same USB port)? Also, have you tried to delete the entire Harddrive (all sectors including MBR - not just inside the partitions?) so the "volume" itself has to be reinitialized by windows? Also did you check the flash drive for any hardware problems?

Comment: It happened only once for me, it's only this USB HD. And yeah it make it on every port or computer. Albeit, I didn't try with my personal computer (only with computer in my office).
I'll try what you said, and also on my own personal computer ! I'll keep you informed, thx

Comment: great, let me know

Comment: Hello @Albin ! Sorry for this long period without any answer. I finally went through the problem, and you were right ! **I have deleted everything, including MBR**... and now my USB HD is working. To do that I have used **Rufus 3.1** ( https://rufus.akeo.ie/ ).
I selected "Non bootable key", "MBR" and "NTFS", started the program and now I can see my USB hardrive.
Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted my comment as an answer, feel free to "accept" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to delete the entire Harddrive (all sectors including MBR - not just inside the partitions?) so the "volume" itself has to be reinitialized by windows.

One option to do that would be to used 3rd party sorftware, e.g. [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie), currently Version 3.1:

Selected the following and start the program:

- "Non bootable key"
- "MBR"
- "NTFS"